# Using Thread.VolatileWrite() with array parameters

Tags: .net, multithreading

I want to use `Thread.VolatileWrite()` (or an equivalent function) to change the value of a `T[]` field, so that the updated value is immediately visible to all other threads. However, the method does not provide a generic version, and I'm not able to use the `Object` overload since it takes a `ref` parameter.

Is there an alternative? Would `Interlocked.Exchange<T>` do the job? Is there a better way to achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`VolatileWrite` is only useful if you also use `VolatileRead`; the `volatile` modifier is easier to use, but I wonder if it wouldn't be simpler to use synchronization - perhaps a [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) (since it sounds like you have lots of readers).

`Interlocked.Exchange<T>` simply performs the get and set as an atomic operation; it doesn't (AFAIK) make any volatility claims (indeed, the compiler even tells you that a `volatile` field won't be treated as `volatile` when used as a `ref` argument).

---

Edit to clarify "it doesn't (AFAIK) make any volatility claims" - the behaviour of `Interlocked` is predictable, and you should see updates immediately on other thread **as long as** they also use `Interlocked`; my point is that if one thread uses `Interlocked`, and another relies on `volatile` (to talk to the same field), I don't know of any guarantees. Stick to one or the other for **all** access.

Comment: So you mean that, unless I use `VolatileRead` too, other threads may still have a cached value of the field?

Comment: Exactly. Hence the `volatile` modifier to make this simpler.

Comment: I was trying to use it in favor of using a volatile field, since that field is accessed very frequently, but only written to very, very few times (e.g. accessed 3n times, while written log(n) times only). So I thought I could introduce VolatileWrite only in write cases...

Comment: @Hosam: The problem is that unless the reading threads know to make sure they don't get a cached version, they could just not both looking at the newly published version. In fact, I believe that .NET (i.e. the MS CLI implementation) makes all writes volatile anyway - it's reads that need extra care.

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe use the [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) modifier. But check the documentation to see that the limitation don't apply to your case. And there is probably a performance penalty for using it.

**Update:** About using Interlocked. Notice that the documentation doesn't state that the changed value is visible to all threads. So it is probably not the same. But if you are in a situation that this is important. You must investigate further all the concurrency disaster possibilities.

Comment: Thank you. I am already using the volatile modifier, and I was hoping I could avoid its penalty by calling VolatileWrite explicitly. (Please see my comment on Marc's answer.) Thanks.